# SQL DataBase correction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Device that send event on a SQL data base. The event a log like this:

```
index|eventNumber|TriggerTime|RecoverTime
```

The issue I have is if they have a power off/on on the device it create sont unrecover event like this

```
index|eventNumber|TriggerTime|RecoverTime
1|2|2020-04-03 8:00|2020-04-03 8:10
2|3|2020-04-03 8:00|2020-04-03 8:30
3|3|2020-04-03 8:20|NULL
4|2|2020-04-03 8:21|2020-04-03 8:23
5|3|2020-04-03 8:40|NULL
```

What I want to do is to copy the triggerTime of the next event with the same eventNumber in the recoverTime. Like this

```
index|eventNumber|TriggerTime|RecoverTime
1|2|2020-04-03 8:00|2020-04-03 8:10
2|3|2020-04-03 8:00|2020-04-03 8:30
3|3|2020-04-03 8:20|2020-04-03 8:40
4|2|2020-04-03 8:21|2020-04-03 8:23
5|3|2020-04-03 8:40|NULL
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select el.*,
       coalesce(recovertime,
                lead(triggertime) over (partition by eventnumber order by triggertime)
               ) as new_recovertime
from eventlog;
```

If you need this in an `update`, you can use `join`

```
update eventlog el join
       (select el.*,
               lead(triggertime) over (partition by eventnumber order by triggertime) as new_recovertime
        from eventlog
       ) el2
       on el2.eventnumber = el.eventnumber and
          el2.eventtime = el.eventtime
    set recovertime = new_recovertime
    where recovertime is null and new_recovertime is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

the mysql server is 5.7, so it doesn't have the lead fonction. I find a way to do a select to that add a colone with the value to put in the null place, but I don't know how to put it in an update.

```
    (SELECT 
 event_index, event_log_index, `trigger_time@timestamp`, `recover_time@timestamp`
 , (SELECT 
     `trigger_time@timestamp`
    FROM 
     plc.`test` alfabetInner 
    WHERE
      alfabetInner.`trigger_time@timestamp` > plc.`test`.`trigger_time@timestamp` AND alfabetInner.`event_log_index` = plc.`test`.`event_log_index`
    ORDER BY 
      `trigger_time@timestamp` ASC
    LIMIT 0, 1      
   ) AS 'Nexttrigger_time@timestamp'

FROM 
 plc.`test`  
ORDER BY
 `trigger_time@timestamp` ASC)
```